# plugin has performed illegal operation

Tags: firefox, plugins

I am developing a firefox plugin. When i am using debug mode dll ,it works fine but when i am using release dll it is showing me a prompt saying that Plugin has performed an illegal operation.
Can anybody tell me why this is happening  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical development approach is to turn on logging.

It looks like this is easy to do in FF. From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/setting_up_extension_development_environment

> extensions.logging.enabled = true. This will send more detailed information about installation and update problems to the Error Console. (Note that the extension manager automatically restarts the application at startup sometimes, which may mean you won't have time to see the messages logged before the automatic restart happens. To see them, prevent the automatic restart by setting the environment NO_EM_RESTART to 1 before starting the application.)